# How do I add HSTS headers to my nginx / react app on app engine flex?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, app-engine-flexible, hsts

I've got a react app running via nginx on app engine flexible environment, using a custom domain and SSL, and I'd like to add HSTS headers.

I know from what resources i could find that my application code itself needs to serve the headers, rather than putting them directly in any app.yaml file,

so i figured i could do it through my nginx.conf as described in https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/

However,  my nginx block is specific for responding to app engine requests, so it's really only listening on `:8080` -

I was under the impression that all requests come through from app engine to :8080 so I wouldn't imagine adding another server block to listen on 443 would do anything?

maybe i'm better off having the react app somehow serve the header?

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to 
this
  # directory.
  access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
  error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name localhost;
    root /src/build;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http' ) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, now i feel foolish.

All I had to do was add the following line in the right place:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
```

I was initially trying to add it just above the `if ( $http_x_forwarded...` part and I was also trying it with the `always` keyword at the end as well and my deploy kept failing with this line in it.

Anyway,  it works!

the full resulting nginx.conf  is as follows:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console 
  # when logged to this directory.
  access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
  error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name localhost;
    root /src/build;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http' ) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";        

    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log off;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer? For future reference of the community. If I recall correctly, you have to wait 2 days to do so.

Comment: Yup, once I can I will!

Comment: Hi phlare, is it possible to just set the Strict-Transport-Security header without affecting the other app engine flex defaults? I'm fine with how my server is configured now, I just want to enforce HTTPS over all client connections. What would the nginx.conf look like if I wanted to do that?