# How do I test that HSTS header has been added successfully to my nginx / react app on app engine flex?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

In my app, there are 3 different nginx server containing 3 different container - Legacy, API and React. Now the issue is for React, I have already added the header - **Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin** in the react config file of nginx under docker.

But how and where can I test that the header **Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin** has been added?

I tried using fetch API inside App.tsx file, but it is unable to read header response. showing blank.

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch( "<API>")
            .then((res) => console.log(res.headers))
    }
```

O/P: Headers{}

So can some one suggest me how can I read the response header particularly for react container?

Comment: May be this one helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132258/how-do-i-add-hsts-headers-to-my-nginx-react-app-on-app-engine-flex

Comment: I already check this. Here it is mentioned that how can i add but i actually need how can i test the header.